# How can I make an average of a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the average of the entries starting at B4. Tell me what should be changed in my code. Im new to vba.

```
    Range("F13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Range(Range("B4").End(xlDown)))"
```

Edit:
And how does it work in this case?

```
Range("F17").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F17").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(R[-13]C[-2]:R[-10]C[-2])=0,10^99,COUNT(" & Range(Range("D4"), Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"
```

Comment: *R1C1-Style:* `Range("F13").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(" & Range("B4", Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"`or *A1-Style:* `Range("F13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Range("B4", Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have the actual formula in the cell (so it will automatically update if the values on the worksheet change) then you could do it like:

```
Sub test()
  Dim rgStart As Range, rgStop As Range, rg As Range
  Set rgStart = Range("B4")
  Set rgStop = rgStart.End(xlDown)
  Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgStop)
  Range("F13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & rg.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

...that is the tidier way to do it  (more code but easier to understand).

This is the same code but more "compact":

```
Sub test()
  Range("F13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Range(Range("B4"), Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"
End Sub
```

If you don't actually want the formula in the cell (so it's a static value) you can still call the worksheet `AVERAGE` function with [`Application.WorksheetFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction), like:

```
Sub test()
  Dim rgStart As Range, rgStop As Range, rg As Range
  Set rgStart = Range("B4")
  Set rgStop = rgStart.End(xlDown)
  Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgStop)
  Range("F13") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rg)
End Sub
```

...and again, "compacted":

```
Sub test()
  Range("F13") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Range("B4"), Range("B4").End(xlDown)))
End Sub
```

Comment: God bless your `code`!

Comment: ... and as a hint to possible newcomers: fully qualify your range references, as an unqualified range ref implicitly refers to the active sheet which needn't be that one actually in focus.

Comment: Code see in question! but somhow it quite doesnt work in this new case where there is an if sentence. Also there are those R[-13]C[-2] in the same formula. How can you make this in the right syntax?